# Reusable tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

I basically have multiple blocks. Around 8. Each has a slightly different design. but all the same html. How can I structure the code so that I can change the h2/button design, but use the same html structure?

```
<div>
 <h1></h1>
 <button></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Tailwind* is a [Utility-First](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/utility-first) CSS framework. In traditional CSS frameworks you would probably want to create classes for each of your blocks, named `.introduction-block .sales-block .whatever-block`. However, in Tailwind you generally try to avoid writing custom CSS classes and instead use the provided *utility* classes when possible. So for your problem I would suggest that you simply apply these utility classes and modify your blocks where needed, e.g.

```html
  <div class="bg-red-200 px-10">
    <h1 class="text-lg font-bold">Headline 1</h1>
    <div>Some simple text without class here.</div>
  </div>

   <div class="bg-blue-200 px-10">
    <h1 class="text-lg font-bold">Headline 2</h1>
    <div class="italic">Some italic text.</div>
  </div>

   <div class="bg-purple-800 px-10 text-gray-200 ">
    <h1 class="text-lg font-bold">Headline 3</h1>
    <div class="text-sm">The last block</div>
  </div>
```

[Link to Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/UtAOHU4jMO)

I suggest that you have a look at their documentation, it's honestly one of the best I've ever read.

You could certainly also make use of JavaScript frameworks like Vue3 in combination with Tailwind to [create components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#reusing-components) for each of your blocks and reuse them to avoid code duplication in the HTML (for example define a `BlockComponent` which always has the structure div>h1+div and then style them according to some passed properties).

I know this was quite a generic answer but I hope it helps anyway.